# Android OpenGL Es 3.0 Create Circle

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, geometry, opengl-es-3.0

I have tried implementing suggestions from other posts such as:

- [How to draw basic circle in OpenGL ES 2.0 Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140117/how-to-draw-basic-circle-in-opengl-es-2-0-android)
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47584/how-to-draw-a-smooth-circle-in-android-using-opengl
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26232/drawing-a-circle-in-opengl-es-android-squiggly-boundaries

as well as many others on Stack OverFlow, but none are working.

Either I am calling the

```
draw()
```

method and not getting an output or the code is out of date and is a bit pointless to use.

I am trying to create just a basic circle. I can create Triangles and Squares perfectly fine however I have no clue how to properly implement creating a circle.

Based on my current knowledge a circle is created from just adding more vertices, such as the illustration below. However I do not know how to implement this.

[image]

This is my current SurfaceView Renderer:

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
//Project Matrix
private float mMatrix[] = new float[16];
private Circle mCircle;
private Triangle mTriangle;

// Called once to set up the view's opengl es environment
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config){

    //Set the background frame color
    GLES30.glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

    mTriangle = new Triangle();
    mCircle = new Circle();
}

// Called for each redraw of the view
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){
    //gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Redraw background color
    //GLES30.glClear(GLES30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    //mTriangle.draw();

   Matrix.orthoM(mMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
   mCircle.draw(mMatrix);
}

// Called if the geometry of the view changes (example is when the screen orientation changes from landscape to portrait
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height){
    // Called if the geometry of the viewport changes
    GLES30.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES30.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES30.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES30.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES30.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

}
```

My SurfaceView is as follows:

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);

        //Create an OpenGl 3.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(3);

        mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();

        //Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(mRenderer);

        //Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
```

My current Circle implementation is as follows:

```
 public class Circle {

    private  int mProgram, mPositionHandle, mColorHandle, mMVPMatrixHandle ;
    private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
    private float vertices[] = new float[364 * 3];
    float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                    "}";

    Circle(){
        vertices[0] = 0;
        vertices[1] = 0;
        vertices[2] = 0;

        for(int i =1; i <364; i++){
            vertices[(i * 3)+ 0] = (float) (0.1 * Math.cos((3.14/180) * (float)i ));
            vertices[(i * 3)+ 1] = (float) (0.2 * Math.sin((3.14/180) * (float)i ));
            vertices[(i * 3)+ 2] = 0;
        }


        Log.v("Thread", "" + vertices[0] + "," + vertices[1] + "," + vertices[2]);
        ByteBuffer vertexByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        vertexByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mVertexBuffer = vertexByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        mVertexBuffer.position(0);
        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES30.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES30.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        GLES30.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES30.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES30.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        int shader = GLES30.glCreateShader(type);
        GLES30.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES30.glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }


    public void draw (float[] mvpMatrix){

        GLES30.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3,
                GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false,12
                ,mVertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");



        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        GLES30.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES30.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);



        // Draw the triangle
        GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 364);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you initialised GLSurfaceView like  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-glsurfaceview.html ?

Comment: Yes I will update my Post

Comment: I have added a lot of my code now, hope this helps.

Comment: 1. Please check that gl es 3.0 is supported on you device. 2. Using log please make sure that your onDrawFrame is called

Comment: It is supported as I have the newest android on the market. Opengl Es 3.0 is APi 18 and above. Also OnDrawFrame does get called. It runs my triangle no problem

Comment: So looks like you are using Open GL ES 1.0 code for drawing. Use example from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19558553/919150

Comment: Like @AndreyICE says, you're mixing ES 1.x code into the ES 3.0 code. That can't possibly work. While ES 3.0 is an extension of ES 2.0, it is entirely different from ES 1.x, and completely incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19558553/919150.
2. Replace GLES20 to GLES30
3. Declare projection matrix in renderer as

   private float mMatrix[] = new float[16];
4. Init matrix as

   Matrix.orthoM(mMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
5. Draw circle

   mCircle.draw(mMatrix);

Comment: I will try this later tonight and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks I will update my code in this post so that it may help others :)

Comment: Can someone explain how to draw a 2D circle with centre at x,y and radius of r ?  I want a simple Circle.draw(x,y,r) method but every example seems to have the vertices and radius hardcoded in the class and no obvious way of setting that at runtime.  No doubt there is a really simple answer to this somewhere!

Comment: for transration (X,Y) and resizing (R) runtime in Open GL you should use matrixes.